How to use StreamProvider with a FireBase QuerySnapshot
I'm following a very old tutorial which use StreamProvider.  The API has changed quite a bit and now has an intitialData argument but I don't know what to assign it.
The class Home.dart looks like this:
  //const Home({super.key});
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot?>.value(
      value: DatabaseService(uid: '').brews,
      initialData: null,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Brew Crew'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
          elevation: 0.0,
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: Text('logout'),
              onPressed: () async {
                await _auth.signOut();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: BrewList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The class Database.dart looks like this:
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;

  DatabaseService({required this.uid});
  // collection reference
  final CollectionReference brewCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('brews');

  Future updateUserData(String sugars, String name, int strength) async {
    return await brewCollection.doc(uid).set({
      'sugars': sugars,
      'name': name,
      'strength': strength,
    });
  }
  // get brews stream
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> get brews {
    return brewCollection.snapshots();
  }
}

The code compiles but throws an exception because of the null.
Instance of 'BrewUser'
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNullException was thrown building BrewList(dirty, dependencies:
[_InheritedProviderScope<QuerySnapshot<Object?>?>], state: _BrewListState#7ae11):
Error: The widget BrewList tried to read Provider<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> but the matching
provider returned null.

To fix the error, consider changing Provider<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> to
Provider<QuerySnapshot<Object?>?>.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  BrewList
  BrewList:file:///C:/Users/Chris/source/repos/firebase-example/brew_crew/lib/screens/home/home.dart:33:15

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 296:3       throw_
packages/provider/src/provider.dart 307:9                                         of packages/brew_crew/screens/home/brews_list.dart 15:28                             build

There is an old post that is similar but it is no longer valid:
initial data for StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value flutter

"throws an exception because of the null" Please edit your question to include the exact error message and complete stack trace.

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

@puf-FrankvanPuffelen I put in the stack trace.  Thanks for the help.

@AlexMamo does the stack trace give you any clues?
